# Send Auto messages from whatsapp

Tags: c#, sql, api, whatsapp, whatsapi

I have More than 1000 Numbers in a data base.i need to send happy birthday message to the number if the user is using whatsapp. Is this possible?i don't mind if i need to be pay or what..is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[deprecated]
the best way is using : https://github.com/rquiroz/WhatsAPINet

that´s a sample code

```
   WhatsApp wa = new WhatsApp("your number", "your password", "pankaj", false, false);
wa.OnConnectSuccess += () =>
{
    Response.Write("connect");
    wa.OnLoginSuccess += (phno,data) =>
    {
        wa.SendMessage("to", "msg");
    };

    wa.OnLoginFailed += (data) =>
    {
        Response.Write("login failed"+data);
    };
    wa.Login();
};
wa.OnConnectFailed+= (ex)=>
{
    Response.Write("connection failed");
}
```

Comment: how to create **your password**??? I have tried WART executables. But I am getting error message like "Whatsapp stopped supporting spammers".... Is there any other way to create IMEI password to use this code successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need an mobile application that should do it? If so i don't think there is any application like that in the market. Until now Whatsapp has not exposed any of their apis for developers to take advantages of its functionality.

Comment: Mobile or Desktop i don't mind is it possible to do it?